# Oh Sunday morning, you gave me no warning of what was to be

Tags: discussion

I am new here (6th day) but love it.

Today is Sunday, and I notice that the quality of the questions is way down. I'm guessing that it's crunch time, and a lot of people with homework questions are posting.

Is this a fair assumption? Are Sundays always like this? (Admittedly I have a very small sample size.)

Comment: To be perfectly frank, I’ve been wondering the same thing myself,

Comment: @tchrist - I feel as though I might be aiding and abetting cheating in answering the questions, so I have stopped, which is a shame.

Comment: Perhaps people’s homework comes due on Monday morning?

Comment: It does in the US. :-)

Comment: Man and I thought September was bad.  Now it’s every Sunday.

Comment: Eternal September.

Comment: Susan, you might then find that when you're faced with these questions, you didn't really know the information as well as you think, but Sunday low-quality questions is a well-known phenomenon due to a lot of people who ask from India. I think community should  decide to send one of its members, as tchrist,  there to investigate the matter.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider You. Have. No. Idea.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider - "All in favor..." ;-)

Comment: Maybe some folks just have more time to post their question on the weekend, and homework has nothing to do with it.